# Wordpress video post won't let me enter Youtube video ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, video, youtube

When trying to submit a video, Wordpress requires me to input a valid url like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMbM-ERy2Lk, but if I go to the post afterwards there is an error loading the video because the `src` of the `iframe` is

`src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMbM-ERy2Lk?autoplay=0&wmode=transparent&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fcollectively.dev"`

So the solution is obviously to just enter in the youtube ID `NMbM-ERy2Lk` but whenever I try that I get the flash message `Please enter a valid URL address` and am not allowed to publish or preview the post.

Does anyone know what is going on or how I could disable this message?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the answer is in the database in the `wp_options` table under option `wpcf-fields` (which was ID 249 for me). I went in and removed `a:2:{s:6:\"active\";s:1:\"1\";s:7:\"message\";s:32:\"Please enter a valid URL address\";}}`. I'm not 100% sure if that's how to do it, but this can at least point anyone having a similar problem in the right direction.

Edit: Looking even more into this I've found that all these things can be changed within `Dashboard > Types`